# GPT Calculation Program for Matrix

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, quantization

I have a problem calculating a matrix. I don't know how to find this manual matrix, or do I need a program?

I tried to calculate it but I'm having difficulty, I use several types of methods to calculate but no results

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Image 3:

[image]

Comment: try to post this in matlab or math StackExchange bro, we don't know this

Comment: This is tagged as `python`. Can we see the code you have so far?

Comment: I did not create a code to calculate the rho matrix, I used the matrix directly to make diagrams but it is necessary to find the rho matrix and the expressions of f1 and f2, please I need 'help